# Django not installing inside virtual environment

Tags: django, virtualenv

I am starting a project from scratch, and I noticed that when I run 'pip install django' on my main folder, it says 'requirement already satisfied'. However, when I try to run the 'python manage.py startproject ' it says 'Import error: Couldn´t import Django'. How do I solve this? It worked on another project I started 2 weeks ago, now is not working.

When I check the env/lib/site-packages, there is nothing about django there actually.

Comment: This is due to your Python interpreter. if you are in VSCode, press `f1` type `Python: Select Interpreter` and use the one made in your venv (most likely with a star icon)

Comment: Please share the screen shot of error message aloing with IDE

Comment: Did you activate the environment? It usually adds the environment name to the prompt. Also, you can use `which python` and `which pip` to check which environment you are using.

Comment: Maybe your virtual environment is corrupted. Try creating another fresh environment. Activate it. Do `pip list` and then `pip install django`.

Answer (score 0):

try `django-admin startproject` instead of `manage.py startproject`

Comment: I already tried that. What I think I did that worked, was upgrading pip... Somehow after that when I install django, it ends up in the libs folder of the current project